# Application specific do not disturb

Tags: ios, applications, notifications, do-not-disturb

Is there a way on iOS to turn on the *Do not Disturb* feature on an app-per-app basis? I have some apps I only use for work related purposes, and I'd like them to go silent on non working hours (to try and recover from *workaholism*) but I'd still like to receive regular notifications from other apps.

If that's not possible, any suggested workarounds?

Comment: I would love to see this, while the DND was a welcome feature it falls short.  There are things I need to be able to leave on, and spammier things that should be turned off.  In short, Apple really should add a switch per app to the Do not Disturb settings.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that I see a lot is to ask your workplace for a dedicated work phone - if they expect you to be reachable outside of office hours, then they've likely got some legal obligation to provide this.

When you're not working, turn it off.

On the other hand, if you can't just *let go* of work when you get home, that is a whole different problem and possible solutions I can think of are to keep yourself busier by getting a new pet, child or lover. This is especially true if you already have at least one of these.

Comment: I am a freelancer, and it's just really easy to get caught in the *I am always working* attitude. I am being much stricter with myself, by not taking actions outside my available hours, but I'd lie if I said that when I receive a notification from work it doesn't phase me at all. Work phone is the obvious solution, but I don't want to carry around two phones with me most of the time, especially since I think software should be able to solve this issue by now. Thanks for your tip though! It's not really that I am not busy enough,it's that my head needs to be free from those thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

**Screen Time** will be [available](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-12-preview/) in iOS 12 and it has the ability to mark some applications as off-limits (snoozing) between certain hours. This may suit your needs.